# GROUP BY Aggregation with COUNT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to know how to join tables in order to get a sort of a pivot.

```
table1            table2

col1  | col2      col1
------+------     -----
  1   |   A         A
  1   |   B         B
  1   |   C         C
  2   |   A         D
  2   |   A         E
  2   |   A         
  2   |   B
```

This code will return first two columns as I would like to (It will list every table2 entry for each table1 entry grouped) but I don't know how to continue to get the count for how many col2 occurancies are in table1. I would like to list zeros as well.

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col1
FROM table1, table2
GROUP BY table1.col1, table2.col1;
```

**Expected result:**

```
 col1  | col2  | col3
-------+-------+----
  1    |   A   |  1
  1    |   B   |  1
  1    |   C   |  1
  1    |   D   |  0
  1    |   E   |  0
  2    |   A   |  3
  2    |   B   |  1
  2    |   C   |  0
  2    |   D   |  0
  2    |   E   |  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *Cartesian* query:

```sql
SELECT 
    table1.col1, 
    table2.col1 as col2, 
    Abs(Sum([table1].[col2]=[table2].[col1])) AS col3
FROM 
    table1, 
    table2
GROUP BY  
    table1.col1, 
    table2.col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a query with joins, aggregations and correlated subquery as below:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE col2=t1.col2 AND col1=t1.col1) as col3
  FROM (SELECT t1.col1,max(col2) as col2,count(col2) as ct 
          FROM table2 t2 
          JOIN table1 t1 
            ON t2.col1=t1.col2 
         GROUP BY t1.col1) t2
 RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT tt1.col1,t2.col1 as col2 
               FROM table2 t2
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct col1 FROM table1 ) tt1
               ) t1
    ON t2.col2=t1.col2;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=43e8edc13afd059006234c91d75cca14)</kbd>